# Create a Trigger to Modify the effect of 1 related column to all other related Columns

Tags: sql, triggers

If we have 3 Tables with respective columns.

`Employee (Emp_ID, Emp_Name, City_ID)`

`City (City_ID, City_Name, Country_ID)`

`Country (Country_ID, Country_Name)`

Create a trigger which will help to Insert/Delete/Update the `Country` or `City` and Corresponding modify the `Employee` table and `City` Table.

Answer (score 0):

Your tables seem like well formed(Normalized), so instead of writing trigger for your tables you can use Primary-Foreign with Cascade Update/Delete option and I guess you have done this already, because in your tables you have used `_ID` columns, Insert record based on Base Table in Child Table like:

```
INSERT INTO country VALUES(1,'India');

INSERT INTO city VALUES(1,'Chandigarh',1);
INSERT INTO city VALUES(2,'Amritsar',1);

INSERT INTO employee VALUES(1,'emp 1',1);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(2,'emp 11',2);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(3,'emp 111',1);
```

OR

if you want to remove child records by using `trigger` you can use `AFTER DELETE` trigger, like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER del_city_on_contry 
AFTER DELETE ON contry
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM city WHERE
  country_id = :old.country_id
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER del_emp_on_city
AFTER DELETE ON city 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM employee WHERE
  city_id = :old.city_id
END;
/
```

Comment: My Question is different as if we remove the country from Country table and it should also remove the City and Employee belong to same country

Comment: in this case you have to update your child table columns with `Cascade Delete` option, as I mentioned in the description.

Comment: Thanks @Nikhil     (Is it applicable with Trigger also and How please provide me a code)

Comment: is it necessary to use OLD or NEW References?

Comment: Yes @Navjeet we are triggering event when first country deleted. so we need to get which country is deleted, with OLD we will get country id, so now on base of that we can delete from city.

so, we must have to use OLD reference, it will work in Oracle, I don't have idea about other Databases.